# Prove $xy'+ay=f(x)$ has only one bounded solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $xy'+ay=f(x)$, where $a>0$ and $f(x)$ is a continuous and bounded function on $(0,\infty)$ that satisfies $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)=b$. Prove that the equation has only one solution which is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

I was only able to prove that there can't be more than one bounded solution: suppose there are two solutions $y_1,y_2$ which are bounded $|y_1(x)|\leq M,|y_2(x)|\leq K$. Then $y_1-y_2$ solves the homogeneous equation $g'+\frac{a}{x}g=0$. But the general solution to this equation is $g(x)=Cx^{-a}$. Since $a>0$ we have $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}g(x)=C\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x^{-|a|}=\infty$, therefore the solutions are not bounded on $(0,\infty)$ which contradicts the fact that $|y_1-y_2|\leq|y_1|+|y_2|\leq M+K$.

However I fail to prove that such (bounded) solution exists (I tried to prove that the integral which we obtain when finding the solution to the original equation is bounded, but I didn't succeed).

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation can be written as
$$(x^ay(x))'=x^{a-1}f(x)$$
Hence the general solution is
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{x^a}\left(\int_1^x t^{a-1}f(t) dt +y(1)\right).$$
Is there a value of $y(1)$ such that the limit of $y(x)$ at $0^+$ is finite? How many?

Well, we need that $y(1)=\int_0^1 t^{a-1}f(t) dt$. Then 
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{x^a}\int_0^x t^{a-1}f(t) dt$$
and by using L'Hopital,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}y(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^{a-1}f(x)}{ax^{a-1}}=\frac{b}{a}.$$

Finally note that if $|f(x)|\leq M$ for $x>0$ then
$$|y(x)|\leq \frac{M}{x^a}\int_0^x t^{a-1} dt=\frac{M}{a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, $x^{a-1}$ is an integrating factor. Consider
$$
(x^ay(x))'=x^{a-1}f(x)
$$
and integrate to get
$$
x^ay(x)=\int_0^s s^{a-1}f(s)\,ds=f(\theta(x)·x)·\int_0^s s^{a-1}\,ds=\frac1a\,f(\theta(x)·x)·x^a
$$
with $\theta(x)\in(0,1)$ per the mean value theorem of integration. Thus
$$
y(x)=\frac1a·f(\theta(x)·x)
$$
is a solution with $y(0)=\frac{b}a$.